# C# COM, default property is throwing error no. 438

Tags: c#, vba, com, activex, typelib

I am writing an ActiveX COM control in C#. In this control I have a property called 'Value', which I am trying to expose as default property.

Here is the Typelib definition:

```
[id(0x00000002), propget, bindable, requestedit, displaybind, defaultbind, helpstring("Returns/sets the current date.")]
HRESULT Value([out, retval] VARIANT* pRetVal);

[id(0x00000002), propput, bindable, requestedit, displaybind, defaultbind, helpstring("Returns/sets the current date.")]
HRESULT Value([in] VARIANT pRetVal);
```

The Property implementation is simple :

```
public object Value
        {
            get { return BaseControl.Value.Date; }
            set
            {
               DateTime dt;              
                //BaseControl is a DateTimePicker control.
               BaseControl.Value = DateTime.TryParse((value ?? "").ToString(), out dt) ? dt : DateTime.Today;
            }
        }
```

When using this control in VBA, I able to Set\Get the `Value` property like this

```
Private Sub Test()
    Me.DTPicker1.Value = Date - 5
End Sub
```

But when I am trying to use the default version,

```
Private Sub Test2()
    '/Default property access
    Me.DTPicker1 = Date - 5
End Sub
```

It throws the error,

> 438: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Any idea, why the default mode is not working?

Comment: The `defaultbind` attribute is for [bindable members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/midl/defaultbind), which are not the same as default properties. In order to make a property a default, it should have a dispatch ID of zero.

Comment: The default property always has id=0.  Your Value property is id 2.  We can't guess what you assigned.  Probably nothing, as the error message suggests.

Comment: Comintern and Hans, thanks a-ton  for the response. I corrected the DispId as 0 in the Interface and the IDL for the property and now it works without any error.

Comment: please answer yourself then